# Tab Bar color different on iOS 14 and iOS 15

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using the newest version of Xcode.

My iOS app is build with a Tab Bar Controller. The main Views of the View Controllers that are connected to the Tab Bar Controller have a green Background color. This will make the menu bar at the top (with time, network …) green and will make the Tab Bar have a slight green touch, on iOS 14, like this:

[image: iOS 14]

But since iOS 15 the Tab Bar is fully green instead of translucent with a green touch. It looks like this:

[image: iOS 15]

Why that? How can I have the same effect on iOS 15 as on iOS 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "UIBarsApplyChromelessEverywhere")
```

Objective-C:

```
[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"UIBarsApplyChromelessEverywhere"];
```

This will also fix UINavigationBar and UIToolbar.

Comment: Thanks, great, this is working. I had to put it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to make it work from the first start on.

Comment: Call it before any kind of UI gets instantiated. For example in your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application